# how to initialize marquee tag jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using simple marquee tag in my code and its working fine.
But issue is at that page i added dynamically some data in marquee tag.
So when new data added in marquee tag than marquee tag won't scroll all text which is added in it.

Note : its only scrolls the content which was added at the page load but not not the other content which added later

is there any marquee tag initialization in jquery? i try many options to set the width of marquee etc but no success . i try to search-out it initialization method but not found any good solution

Answer (score 0):

The marquee tag is not in the [HTML specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element#Compliance) so it's support in newer browsers is not guaranteed. It's use is highly discouraged.

I would advice use to stop using it and check some [jQuery Plugins](http://download.remysharp.com/marquee.html) to scroll your text dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe you can do something like this:

JQ:

```
$('.marquee').marquee();
```

CSS:

```
.marquee {
      width: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background: #ccc;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>

<div class="marquee">jQuery marquee is the best <b>marquee</b> plugin in the world</div>
```

Also make sure you check this link: http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this. It is worked for me.

HTML element is like this

```
<marquee width="20%" id="our-marquee-id">First content</marquee>
```

jQuery code is like this

```
jQuery(yourSelector).on(yourEvent, function() {
   jQuery("#our-marquee-id").text("New Content");
});
```

If it won't help you, you can try it with delegate event

```
jQuery(document).delegate(yourSelector, yourEvent, function() {
  jQuery("#our-marquee-id").text("New Content");
});
```